# How to make a LiveUSB that keeps programs installed?

Tags: live-usb

I want to make a LiveUSB (what works fine).
But is there a possibility to install programs in it?

Comment: Just information for others with same problem: use ext2 ,ext3 or ext4 does not work.

Comment: if the current answers do not answer your question, please post your own answer with details on how the question was solved.  Once done, you'll be able to accept your own answer to close the thread.  Thanks.

Comment: ... and please dont add "solved" to a question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can install programms, but it is not as stable as a real installation. In that case, I recommend installing Ubuntu directly on the Usb stick, as if it were a HDD. So you must use another usbstick or a livecd...

Use ext2 for system partition. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: Ok ill give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you need to create a Persistent USB.  To do that under Windows you can download [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), once downloaded double click the file, and you are ready to create the presistent USB.  See image below.

[image]

To create a Persistent USB under Ubuntu look at [Live Usb Pendrive Persistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)

Comment: What if i have not a windows version?

Comment: Look at the link at the end of my answer on hoe to create under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just use persistence! Make a new USB using a program that supports persistence, but it should be quite large, at least 2gb. You need to have some extra space on the USB used for the casper rw stuff.

Comment: While this is correct and older users may know what you are talking about,this answer is too vague to help newbies.....could you please edit your question to include instruction on how to use persistence